# Can waves transport temperature? or How to stop atoms from creating heat

Tags: science-based, temperature

I'm working on a story in which a artificial crystal can turn elements into other elements using waves of protons,neutron and electrons in a pattern, but my question is: can cold be transported by the waves? can infra red light do anything? or is there a wave that can calm atoms / lazer that can calm down atoms(make them stop so that the dont create heat)?

or is it scientifically impossible

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE *Credits unknown*! I am afraid I have no idea what your question is. You have a magical crystal that can turn one element into another. But then you suddenly switch to waves. What kind of waves? What are atomic waves supposed to be? And what do infrared have to do with this? Currently it feels like the only sensible answer to your problem is: You already have magic that is doing a lot of stuff that is not possible. What is preventing you from also postulating that magic just works that way in your world? If you have a moment please take the [tour] andvisit the[help]

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE.  Please note that we recommend waiting 24 hours before selecting an answer as the best answer.  We have participants all over the world, and it is the nature of humanity to stop answering questions once you've announced you're satisfied with the results.  Ultimately, this is a disservice to you.  You never know what amazing answer someone might provide.

Comment: Thermal energy into crystals can be modeled via particles called phonons. But those are far from what you are asking

Comment: "atomic waves" pretty much defines temperature within some contexts.

Comment: what I mean by atomic waves is waves atomic size

Comment: Resident nerd speaking. [Lasers can cool atoms down. It is a scientifict fact.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling) If the question gets reopened I will elaborate.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because its edit improved the clarity of the question and I'm interested in @Renan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it can't; cold is the absence of heat energy, heat energy can, and will whether you like it or not, be transmitted from any area with more of it to all adjacent areas with less of it. That's the science answer.

However if you are using magic and referring to ice as an element suggests you are then anything goes and you simply need to define that this is a magical process that works in a particular way.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, im sayin ice as H2O not as the elements, and im trying not to use magic, btw is there a wave that can calm down atoms

Comment: @Creditsunknown Gravity maybe depending on what you mean by calming down an atom, also have a look at [laser traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers) used for extreme cooling in particle physics labs.